# Why does Javascript ignore single line HTML Comments?

Tags: javascript, html, comments

I just tried this code on my browser (Chrome 39, Windows 8) :-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        <!-- 
            document.write("<h1>Hello</h1>");       
        -->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This produces the Header text on the browser. But when I make a slight change- put the HTML comment stuff on a single line,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        <!-- document.write("<h1>Hello</h1>");        -->
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't display anything. 
Why is it so? I don't think HTML comments are in the Javascript standards.

p.s. I know how to put javascript comments. I'm only wondering about this erratic behavior.

Comment: javascript coments are either: // for single line or /* for multi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the way to hide javascript to browsers  that don't recognize the `script` element. The first line is allways ignored: [Hiding script data from user agents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.2)

> **Commenting scripts in JavaScript**
>
> The JavaScript engine allows the string `"<!--"` to occur at the start of a `SCRIPT` element, and
>   **ignores further characters until the end of the line**. JavaScript interprets `"//"` as starting a comment extending to the end of the
>   current line. This is needed to hide the string `"-->"` from the
>   JavaScript parser.
>
> ```
> <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
> <!--  to hide script contents from old browsers
>   function square(i) {
>     document.write("The call passed ", i ," to the function.","<BR>")
>     return i * i
>   }
>   document.write("The function returned ",square(5),".")
> // end hiding contents from old browsers  -->
> </SCRIPT>
> ```

Comment: Yup; so to be clear, the `<!-- -->` syntax is *not* valid for Javascript comments. There is just a special syntax that can be used to hide Javascript from totally-unaware browsers. *However*, you really should never need to use this anymore. All browsers for years know how to handle regular Javascript tags if they have Javascript disabled, or don't support it.